# (Fast) way to detect changes on the screen

Tags: windows, language-agnostic

Is there a better (more elegant) way to detect changes on a screen, than taking screenshots and comparing them?
Or maybe an api call or an event that is fired on this case.

I need to recognize and to evaluate the changed content, the taking-every-second-"100"-screenshots solution, has the disadvantage that i m wasting resources.
Increasing the "waiting"-time if "nothing" happens isn't either a way to handle, then i would  miss changes.

(One of my old solutions was an pixel by pixel/block compare, that was really slow).

That s why i was hopping there is a better way to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: I assume we're talking about general usage and not when just using your application?

Comment: I'd try to find an open source implementation of a VNC server and see what it does.

Comment: There is a much faster way, you can write a filter driver that you insert before the video driver.  The way that Remote Desktop works for example.  Much faster because you only see actual changes and you get a shot at the updates before they are rasterized so you don't have to compare pixels.  Writing drivers, particularly the video flavor, is an advanced technique.  To put it mildly.

Comment: @Hans could you recommence books/tutorials/links to this topic, my keyword google search wasn't helpful.

Comment: @inselberg any solution for this? I also want to detect the change of screen content. Not sure whether there is an event or api for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take two screenshots.
2. Convert them to grey scale
3. Compare the images pixel to pixel.

You can be specific about your ROI. Alternatively, you can check for foreground windows and change in the position of the window.